# After indexing any node to Firebase, how to query in Android? Can I use startAt() and EndAt() function for over 100k child nodes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After indexing any node to Firebase, how to query in Android? Can I use `startAt()` and `EndAt()` function for more than 100k child nodes?

If I use `.IndexOn` in Firebase rules, does it require to add `limitToLast()` or `limitToFirst()` method in my app code?

Answer (score 1):

100K children isn't that many.  The whole purpose of an index is to easily handle very large amounts of data.  There is no requirement to limit the result set, but I seriously doubt sending 100K children to a client app would ever be what you want - how would you store and display all that data on a client app with such limited memory and bandwidth?

You can use any of the sorting and filtering APIs listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), including startAt and endAt.  The number of nodes is never an issue with respect to the use of the query APIs.

Comment: Actually, I want to load data with orderByChild("district") along with startAt() , endAt() and limitToLast(20). After loading 20 item I want to load more data based on the same requirement mentioned above. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Have you given it a try?  If you have, and you're having problems, it sounds like you have a second question to ask on SO.